# Send Emails From Salesforce

Tags: email, send-email, notification

from my org, are sent only emails  to addresses that have a specific domain. Is this a configurable salesforce setting?

Comment: Do you want to limit the emails sent from SF to a particular domain?

Comment: no, on the contrary I want to be able to send mail to everyone but it does not work, only those are sent to recipients with a specific domain and I do not know whether to look for a salesforce setting or if it's a firewall or proxy problem. 
In particular I want to send notifications to users and only those who have emails with a certain domain receive the email the others do not

Comment: Are you using email relay service? A faulty email service can cause this issue. There is no setting in salesforce which allows you to block or restricts domain names in email

Comment: No, section "Email Relaying Properties" is empty.